# Charts in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, chart

I need to create a lot of charts in SharePoint getting data from SharePoint lists using CAML. Type of charts:

- Column chart
- Bar chart
- Pie chart
- Timeline chart

Which tools are recommended to create this kind of charts in SharePoint?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your question will lead to opinon based. As there are too many tools available to prepare Charts.

As you are in SPO, you are going to fetch data using JSOM/REST, so you can integrate [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org).

There are many other available but some are paid such as [JSCharts](http://www.jscharts.com/)

Comment: Yep Chart.js is great and can do most things. D3.js can cover just about everything else. It is obviously an opinion though...

Comment: Yes I understand. But I can not think of a better place to ask for experience. It is a subject in which there are many variants. Thank you in advance for your opinion. Are these tools you mention are free? Do they require access to a component installed on another side like the case of Google chart API? Thank you.

Comment: ChartJs is free and it comes under http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/notes/license.html., also it only require to include js file...